# Difficulty with Twitter API Search

Tags: python, twitter

I'm new to python `Twitter API`.
I have set up auth with twitter, and I tried the search which works fine.

```
t = twitter.Twitter(auth=auth)    
tt = t.search.tweets(q="stackoverflow",rpp=50)
```

This worked fine and I can read the output.

But if I try:

```
for page in range(1,6):
    tt = t.search.tweets(q="stackoverflow", rpp=100, page=page)
```

This crashes with the error:

```
details: {"errors":[{"code":44,"message":"page parameter is invalid"}]}
```

I looked on the Twitter page and it seems that the page parameter is ok as an optional parameter: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search.

Alternatively, how do I get more search results if the rate is limited to 100 results per request.
Is there another work around it?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `max_id` value to iterate through the results. 
Make a first request to the `Twitter API`, read `max_id` from the result and send it in your next request.

From the [`docs`](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/timelines):

> To use max_id correctly, an application’s first request to a timeline endpoint should only specify a count. When processing this and subsequent responses, keep track of the lowest ID received. This ID should be passed as the value of the max_id parameter for the next request, which will only return Tweets with IDs lower than or equal to the value of the max_id parameter. Note that since the max_id parameter is inclusive, the Tweet with the matching ID will actually be returned again, as shown in the following image:

[image]

Use [`Twython`](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython):

```
from twython import Twython

twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN)

# Initial request
result = twitter.search(q='stackoverflow', count=100)

# Get max_id of results
next_max_id = result['search_metadata']['next_results'].split('max_id=')[1].split('&')[0]
# Use max_id in next request 
result = twitter.search(q='stackoverflow', count=100, max_id=next_max_id)
```